# Elasticsearch.net - NEST Scroll keeps returning the same results

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, scroll, nest

I'm trying to understand why an elasticsearch.net NEST scroll call keeps returning the same results. I have an outer loop in my C# application that tracks the current page and it's passed in along with the batch size. I've simplified the code:

```
List<int> ids = GetIds();
int count = _batchSize;
int currentPage = 0;

while (count == _batchSize)
{
    var results = Execute(client => client.Search<Invoice>(s => s
                .Index(indexName)
                .Query(q => q
                .Terms(n => n
                .Field(f => f.Items.FirstOrDefault().MyInformation.FirstOrDefault().ItemID)
                .Terms(ids)))
                .Size(batchSize)
                .From(currentPage * batchSize)
                .Scroll("1m")
           ));

    DoSomethingWithResults();
    count = results.Count();
    currentPage++;
}
```

In the above call the list of ids are ids of nested elements in a one to many relationship with the objects they're contained within. That's why I want to use scroll as I don't know how many Invoice objects will be returned. Every time this is called currentPage is incremented by 1. I had assumed that the next batch from the scroll would be returned.

I think I'm doing something wrong as I'm looking at this as more of a paging flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't quite how the [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) works.

1. First request is to `.Search<T>()` (or `SearchAsync<T>()`), specifying `.Scroll()` time. the response will contain the first set of documents
2. Subsequent requests are to `.Scroll<T>` (or `ScrollAsync<T>()`), passing in the scroll id from the previous request, and a scroll time to keep the scroll open on Elasticsearch. Loop sending scroll requests until a response does not contain any documents.

Take a look at [this answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41754055/1831)

Comment: Thanks again Russ! 
I hadn't noticed that the first and subsequent retrievals were using different call types.
Everything is working working as planed now, I'm excited!