# ElasticSearch Nest. Get aggregation result within timespan excluding another timespan

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Followed by [this question - get unique user within timespan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41739226/elasticsearch-nest-better-code-for-terms-aggregation-and-its-iteration/41754055#41754055), I'd like to filter out users who are appeared only within given timespan.

In example, list of users who visited **only in year 2016, but not in year 2017**. This is not a case when we use filter only `2016` timespan as a user might be appeared in `2017` also. So, the possible trial is to make `[2016..2017 users] - [2017 users]` set.

My trial was to send 2 queries(`[2016..2017 users]` and `[2017 users]`) to ES and filtered out by using `userList_20162017.Except(userList_2017)` in my application.

But it seems very inefficient approach I think. Could we achieve it only with ElasticSearch NEST query?

```
void Main()
{
    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    var twoYearsAgo = new DateTime(2016,1,1);
    var yearAgo = new DateTime(2017,1,1);

    // get 2016..2017 users
    var searchResponse20162017 = client.Search<Visitor>(s => s
        .Size(0)
        .Query(q => q
            .DateRange(c => c.Field(p => p.CreationDate)
                .GreaterThan(twoYearsAgo)
                .LessThan(DateeTime.UtcNow)
            )
        )
        .Aggregations(a => a
            .Terms("unique_users", c => c
                .Field(f => f.OwnerUserId)
                .Size(int.MaxValue)
            )
        )
    );

    // get 2017 users
    var searchResponse2017 = client.Search<Visitor>(s => s
        .Size(0)
        .Query(q => q
            .DateRange(c => c.Field(p => p.CreationDate)
                .GreaterThan(yearAgo)
                .LessThan(DateeTime.UtcNow)
            )
        )
        .Aggregations(a => a
            .Terms("unique_users", c => c
                .Field(f => f.OwnerUserId)
                .Size(int.MaxValue)
            )
        )
    );

    var uniqueUser20162017 = searchResponse20162017.Aggs.Terms("unique_users").Buckets.Select(b => b.KeyAsString).ToList();
    var uniqueUser2017 = searchResponse2017.Aggs.Terms("unique_users").Buckets.Select(b => b.KeyAsString).ToList();

    // Final result. seems so naïve and inefficient.
    var uniqueUser2016Only = searchResponse20162017.Except(searchResponse2017);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do this with a [`filter` sub aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html); first, get the unique ids for the range 2016 and 2017 with a `terms` aggregation, then perform a sub aggregation on this to get those ids that are not in the range for 2017. If the document count for the `terms` aggregation is equal to the document count for the filter aggregation, then this is an id that is only in 2016 and not 2017.

Here's an example

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var defaultIndex = "examples";
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    var examples = new[]{
        new Example(1, new DateTime(2016, 01, 01)),
        new Example(1, new DateTime(2017, 01, 01)),
        new Example(2, new DateTime(2016, 01, 01)),
        new Example(3, new DateTime(2017, 01, 01)),
    };

    client.Bulk(b => b
        .IndexMany(examples)
        .Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor));

    client.Search<Example>(s => s
        .Size(0)
        .Query(q => +q
            .DateRange(c => c.Field(p => p.Date)
                .GreaterThanOrEquals(new DateTime(2016, 01, 01))
                .LessThan(new DateTime(2018, 01, 01))
            )
        )
        .Aggregations(a => a
            .Terms("ids_in_2016_and_2017", c => c
                .Field(f => f.ExampleId)
                .Size(int.MaxValue)
                .Aggregations(aa => aa
                    .Filter("ids_only_in_2016", f => f
                        .Filter(ff => +!ff
                            .DateRange(d => d
                                .Field(p => p.Date)
                                .GreaterThanOrEquals(new DateTime(2017, 01, 01))
                                .LessThan(new DateTime(2018, 01, 01))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
}

public class Example
{
    public Example(int exampleId, DateTime date)
    {
        ExampleId = exampleId;
        Date = date;
    }

    public int ExampleId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

`ExampleId` 2 is only in 2016 and not in 2017, as the doc count for it for 2016 and 2017 is equal to the doc count for only 2016

```
{
  "took" : 10,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 4,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "ids_in_2016_and_2017" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 1,
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "ids_only_in_2016" : {
            "doc_count" : 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 2,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "ids_only_in_2016" : {
            "doc_count" : 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : 3,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "ids_only_in_2016" : {
            "doc_count" : 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

*OP appended: result to get a list of userId.

```
var list = searchResponse1.Aggs.Terms("ids_in_2016_2017").Buckets
                .Select(o => new {
                    UserId = o.Key,
                    DocCount = o.DocCount == ((Nest.SingleBucketAggregate)o.Aggregations["ids_only_in_2016"]).DocCount
                 })
                 .Where(x => x.DocCount == true)
                 .Select(x => x.UserId)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I cannot find documentation about `+q` or `!+ff` syntax in query. Could you give me a link for it?

Comment: @Youngjae Take a look at the `bool` query documentation:https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/bool-queries.html I'm releasing new website documentation shortly that better explains the operators: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/enhancement/great-docs-update/docs/query-dsl/bool-dsl/bool-dsl.asciidoc